# Django rest framework raw queries select not working

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to use a raw query in order to make a JOIN in a many to many relationship, and show it in the Django Rest Framework.

But the "SELECT" part of the query is not working, and it shows whatever the serializer has in "fields" and thus the JOIN is also not working.

serializers.py:

```
class UserTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py:

```
class UserTestQuery(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.raw('SELECT * ' +
                                'FROM users_user ' +
                                'INNER JOIN sysadmin_works_as ON users_user.user_id = sysadmin_works_as.employee_id;')
    serializer_class = UserTestSerializer
```

I want to show a join in the API with these 3 models, so I must use raw SQL. Why is it not working?

And the models I'm using are:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    username = None
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    national_id_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    star_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    app_role = models.ForeignKey(App_roles,related_name='employee',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) #Un Rol_de_Aplicacion le pertenece a muchos usuar
```

```
class Works_as(models.Model):
    work_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    started_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updates_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    r_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    r_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    r_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='works_as',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) 
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position,related_name='works_as',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
```

```
class Position(models.Model):
    position_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    upper_position = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,related_name='positions',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    hierarchy_level = models.OneToOneField(Employee_Hierarchy,related_name='position',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `prefetch_related` and `select_related`?

Comment: Yes, and they are not showing anything

Comment: What do you mean by they aren't showing anything? If you mean no data is returned, have you tried opening a shell and running the queryset that should be generated there?